# Need to frame a regex for a format example hours:minutes example 04:30

Tags: regex

I enter  hours:minutes example 04:30 in a text.on the button click i need to check if this has only numbers, no special chars, no alphabets and specifically the colon in between. Need a regex framed for the same to match. Please help.

Comment: Are two-digit numbers (i.e. `04` for 4) mandatory?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$
```

Answer (score 2):

`^(?:2[0-3]|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]\d$` will work with or without a leading zero.